# Durandal canDeactivate vs window.onbeforeunload possible alternative

Tags: javascript, jquery, single-page-application, durandal, onbeforeunload

Users can edit their profile information. If they attempt to navigate away from the page while changes are present, the desired functionality should be that they are presented with a confirmation box. When I use Durandal's canDeactivate, it is only triggered when I try to navigate to another Durandal page. When I use window.onbeforeunload it is only triggered when I either hard refresh or type in a new URL etc.

Is there any universal solution (unified look and feel) that can catch both of these classes of events in order to prevent users from immediately navigating away from a page?

My two approaches are displayed below:

**Durandal canDeactivate**

```
canDeactivate: function () {
        if ($("#saveButtonsBottom").css('visibility') === 'visible') {
            var title = 'Warning';
            var msg = 'Do you want to leave this page and lose all of your edits to this form?';
            return app.showMessage(msg, title, ['Yes', 'No'])
                .then(function (selectedOption) {
                    return selectedOption === 'Yes';
                });
        }
        return false;
    }
```

**window.onbeforeunload**

```
            window.onbeforeunload = function() {
            if ($("#saveButtonsBottom").css('visibility') === 'visible') {
                var title = 'Warning';
                var msg = 'Do you want to leave this page and lose all of your edits to this form?';
                return app.showMessage(msg, title, ['Yes', 'No'])
                    .then(function (selectedOption) {
                        return selectedOption === 'Yes';
                    });
            }
            return true;
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found in practice that you need both approaches to be sure of the desired behavior.  `window.onbeforeunload` is considered by many to be a bad practice for web applications.

We finally abandoned this approach in our web application in favor of a Work in Progress pattern, where changes are saved (out to a back-end) every 3 seconds.  That way, users can freely move from page to page without ever fearing the loss of their work.  It does require adjusting one's data model, and the ability to turn off validation for works in progress.  A Project document collection--or Projects table, depending on your approach to data--would have a corresponding ProjectDraft document collection or table.

But that's a topic of another discussion.  In the meantime, if you have to take the approach you've given, why not encapsulate the logic in another require-able module?  In other words:

```
var onNavigateOrShutdown = function () {
    var title = 'Warning';
    var msg = 'Do you want to leave this page and lose all of your edits to this form?';
    return app.showMessage(msg, title, ['Yes', 'No'])
        .then(function (selectedOption) {
            return selectedOption === 'Yes';
        });
}
```

and then

```
canDeactivate: function () {
    if ($("#saveButtonsBottom").css('visibility') === 'visible') {
        onNavigateOrShutdown();
    return false;
}
```

and

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if ($("#saveButtonsBottom").css('visibility') === 'visible') {
        onNavigateOrShutdown();
    }
    return true;
};
```

Now, let's move this functionality into a new singleton module called, say, `navigation.manager`.  Then, it's simply a matter of requiring the module wherever you need this logic.  Of course, you can elaborate on `navigation.manager` and have it contain an evented hub that's capable of responding to messages and/or publishing them.